# Angular Validation render ng-valid when form is not valid

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, forms, validation

I have a **wedding RSVP** form

[image]

I am trying hide the DONE submit button and only show it when the form is valid.

```
<form method="POST" action="http://l.bheng.com:8888/wedding" accept-charset="UTF-8" class="ng-pristine ng-pristine ng-valid ng-valid-required ng-valid-email" role="form" id="rsvp-form" name="rsvp-form">
    <input name="_token" type="hidden" value="JK8PC04aF7xGsbcQoTvzz2FV61od1DmGdraiZNwB">
    <div class="col-xs-12 form-group">
        <label for="">Are you attending ? </label>
        <br>
        <label for="going">
            <input type="radio" id="going" value="1" ng-model="going" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-not-empty" name="3"> Yes
        </label>
        <label for="going">
            <input type="radio" id="going" value="0" ng-model="going" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-not-empty" name="4"> No
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 form-group">
        <label for="">Number of total guests ? </label>
        <br>
        <select id="guestNum">
            <option value="1">Just Me</option>
            <option value="2">Me and My +1</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 form-group">
        <label for="">Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="normal ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-empty ng-valid-required" id="name" placeholder="Name" ng-model="name" ng-required="required">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 form-group">
        <label for="">Email</label>
        <input type="email" class="normal ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-empty ng-valid-email ng-valid-required" placeholder="Email Address" id="email" ng-required="required" ng-model="email">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 form-group">
        <label for="">Message</label>
        <textarea id="message" ng-model="message" rows="5" type="text" class="normal ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-empty" placeholder="Message to us "></textarea>
        <grammarly-btn>
            <div data-reactroot="" class="_e725ae-textarea_btn _e725ae-anonymous _e725ae-not_focused" style="visibility: hidden; z-index: 2;">
                <div class="_e725ae-transform_wrap">
                    <div title="Protected by Grammarly" class="_e725ae-status">&nbsp;</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </grammarly-btn>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12" ng-hide="rsvp-form.name.$invalid || rsvp-form.email.$invalid ">
        <a id="rsvp-submit" ng-click="rsvp()" class="button" style="width: 100%;">

                  Done

                  <img src="/img/svg/default.svg" alt="Loading" style="width: 30px; float: right; padding-top: 7px; " class="hidden loading">

                </a>
    </div>
</form>
```

My Done button keep showing no matter what.

How do I stop that ?

How can my form have this class ?

- `ng-pristine`
- `ng-valid` <--- How is it possible ? I'm not even input anything in name/email
- `ng-valid-required` <--- How is it possible ? I'm not even input anything in name/email
- `ng-valid-email` <--- How is it possible ? I'm not even input anything in name/email

**JSfiddle** = https://jsfiddle.net/bheng/Ln3tqzcu/

Comment: Can you provide a working fiddle? My suggestion is that your ```ng-hide``` is looking in the wrong place for data to validate, since your model for 'name', for example, is stored in the scope as ```name``` and not inside the object ```rsvp-form```, but a fiddle can help debugging ;)

Comment: Do you include `ng-pristine ng-pristine ng-valid ng-valid-required ng-valid-email` in the original html??

Comment: @AlonEitan : No  I didn't include that. It auto generate when I refresh the page. I copied it after `view page source`.

Comment: @LucaArgenziano : Here is my fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/bheng/Ln3tqzcu/

Comment: Is it because I have 2 `ng-model="going"` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shouldn't you name your form `rsvpForm` (and all its occurrences) instead of `rsvp-form`? I don't think `rsvp-form` is valid name in JavaScript. And it may be a reason why it does not work. And maybe you should turn off HTML validation with `novalidate` on `form` tag, and use simply `required` instead of `ng-required="required"`, cause IMO it tries to find `$scope.required`, which is `undefined` and directive does not work properly.Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/od62sshv/3/

Comment: Ohh I see, with that Angular is confuse with the directive.... You're 100% right. I didn't think of that. Thanks.

Comment: @ihue and that was a reason of weird behavior?

Comment: I still see the same issue after updating my code base on your suggestion, you may see it here : https://jsfiddle.net/bheng/Ln3tqzcu/

Comment: Is it because I have 2 ng-model="going" ?

Comment: @ihue But where you have Angular included in this fiddle? I don't see ``ng-app` and all Angular stuff like `ng-controller` and others.

Comment: @ihue Few changes (from my answer, but I have added it later and maybe you didn't see them) and I think it work like you expect: https://jsfiddle.net/od62sshv/3/ BTW I think Plunker is better for Angular related simple examples, moreover Plunker is written in Angular :)

Comment: @Pneumokok your fiddle is exactly what I meant in my previous comment when I said "is looking in the wrong place for data to validate". I think you should include the fiddle in the answer, and this will be the right one. Just a note: there's no need to add ng-specific classes to the input fields, since angular inject them automatically based on the ```required``` spec.

Comment: @LucaArgenziano I added fiddle.

Answer (score -1):

The usage for ng-valid is as such:

```
ng-valid="isValid()"
```

Where the expression can be accessed by the DOM and will return a boolean value.
Example:

```
$scope.isValid = function () {
  return True;
}
```

If yo want to make the 'Done' button disappear, though, you want ng-hide, ng-show and preferably, ng-if. Look them up.
ng-valid will only grey-out the button.

EDIT:
Here's a more comprehensive example for ng-valid, for clarity's sake.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="email" class="somethingUnrelated" ng-model="email">
<input type="button" name="confirm" class="somethingElse" ng-valid="isValid()">
```

JS:

```
$scope.isValid = function () {
   if ($scope.email) {
     return $scope.email.length > 0;
   }
 }
```

This would not make your button disappear, only greyed-out.
If you want it gone, replace ng-valid with ng-show.

Comment: OP is using `ng-hide` ....look closer. Don't see what the relevance of `ngValid` is to the issue either. You provided no explanation how it would solve problem

Comment: OP seems to use a great many things i'm not sure he knows how to use.
If he would like his 'Done' button to stop showing, as he says, then he's not looking for ng-valid.

Comment: well it clearly states .. *"I am trying hide the DONE submit button"*

Comment: Agreed. Hence ng-hide, ng-show and ng-if - but the usage is roughly the same for all three.